# Module specific database - zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework version 2, how to configure different databases for different modules. Each module will have access to different database.

```
'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''),
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => '',
    ),
```

placed above code in module.config.php for each module with different DB name

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a module configuration is actually more that the module is providing some configuration for the application. The supplied configuration is merged into a single configuration and therefore using the same configuration key names will cause this data to be overwritten.

So instead use descriptive names - db_user or db_logging etc.

Also it's probably a good idea to look at ServiceManager factories, as you can pull out some common database credentials and then use a different database name depending on which factory is being used.

I've only lightly touched on databases in ZF2 so maybe someone else will offer a better approach.

Comment: Dear DrBeza, i used different name for db as db1 and db2 for each module but its using only one and in other modules getting exceptions